# Read excel file stored in SharePoint Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have an excel file stored in SharePoint document library. I need to read this excel file and get the data Programmatically from the file path.

```
string rangeName = "Sheet1!D43";
            string value = GetRangeValue("abc.xslx", rangeName);
 string url =
             "http://sharepoint1.net/excel/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/docs/" +
              workbookName + "/model/Ranges('" + rangeName + "')?$format=HTML";
```

Here, When I keep this link in browser, I get the desired value in HTML. Now, how can I get it in the c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain the specified query really works, then depending on the preferences at least the following .NET components are available:

- [HttpWebRequest class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [WebClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [HttpClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) (.NET >= 4.5)

Below is provided the example for consuming SharePoint Excel REST services based on [WebClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public class ExcelClient : IDisposable
{

    public ExcelClient(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials)
    {
        WebUri = webUri;
        _client = new WebClient {Credentials = credentials};
    }


    public string ReadRange(string libraryName, string fileName,string rangeName, string formatType)
    {
        var endpointUrl = WebUri + string.Format("/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/{0}/{1}/Model/Ranges('{2}')?$format={3}", libraryName,fileName, rangeName, formatType);
        return _client.DownloadString(endpointUrl);
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public Uri WebUri { get; private set; }

    private readonly WebClient _client;

}
```

**Usage**

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName,password,domain);  
var client = new ExcelClient(webUri, credentials);
var data = client.ReadRange("docs", workbookName, rangeName, "html");
```

Comment: Could you tell me what could be my webUri ? 
I get value at this location : **http://sharepoint1.net/excel/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/docs/" +
              workbookName + "/model/Ranges('" + rangeName + "')?$format=HTML**

Comment: Sure, it is web site url: http://sharepoint1.net/excel  in your case (i am assuming 'excel' is a name of sub site where 'docs' library resides in which excel file 'abc.xslx' is stored)

Comment: I get the Error : **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**. I am on the line ` return _client.DownloadString(endpointUrl);`

Comment: No idea, the specified example works for me.. Try to analyze request error    for example with Fiddler

Comment: Are you **sure** of using the proper syntax: var data = client.ReadRange("docs", "abc.xslx", "Sheet1!D43", "html"); ?

Comment: That error is gone now. but in the data variable i get the html. How can i extract the value from it.

Comment: I would be glad to answer at this question but it is a different question, so please create a new one.

Comment: Btw, i guess this answer was helpful, so you could consider to accept it )

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. But, could you please let me know from the **var data** , how would you actually get the value ?

Comment: Well, at least two options are available 1) you could parse html content, i would suggest this library: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ or 2) you could change the format, for example from html to atom and then parse as Xml

Comment: Appreciate if you could help me with this one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679419/system-net-webexception-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-d

Answer (score 0):

HTML format is no more supported by Excel client. Try using atom format which worked for me

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh124646(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31697768)